# Why is torch complaining about an empty tensor?

Tags: loss-function, pytorch

The `structure_loss` method is supposed to return a loss for ground truth vs predicted masks:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn


def structure_loss(pred, mask):
    weit = 1 + 5 * torch.abs(nn.functional.avg_pool2d(mask, kernel_size=31, stride=1, padding=15) - mask) # here
    wbce = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, mask, reduce='none')
    wbce = (weit * wbce).sum(dim=(2, 3)) / weit.sum(dim=(2, 3))

    pred = torch.sigmoid(pred)
    inter = ((pred * mask) * weit).sum(dim=(2, 3))
    union = ((pred + mask) * weit).sum(dim=(2, 3))
    wiou = 1 - (inter + 1) / (union - inter + 1)
    return (wbce + wiou).mean()


a = torch.Tensor(np.random.uniform(0,1, (352, 352)))
b = torch.Tensor(np.random.uniform(0,1, (352, 352)))
print(structure_loss(a,b))
```

However, I test it on  dummy data I get

```
 File "binary_cross_entropy_for_random_array.py", line 8, in structure_loss
    weit = 1 + 5 * torch.abs(nn.functional.avg_pool2d(mask, kernel_size=31, 
stride=1, padding=15) - mask) # here
RuntimeError: non-empty 2D or 3D (batch mode) tensor expected for input

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to generate tensors suitable for this method?

Answer (score 1):

Because the structure loss expects a 4D tensor (NCHW), the tensors you're generating are 2D (only a height and width, H and W).

For an arbitrary batch size, N = 2 and channel dimension, C = 1 (grayscale). Your code would be:

```
a = torch.Tensor(np.random.uniform(0,1, (352, 352)))
b = torch.Tensor(np.random.uniform(0,1, (352, 352)))
print(structure_loss(a,b))
```